# Why the compiler cast long to int?

Tags: java, long-integer

```
1 public class Foo {
2   public static void main(String[]a){
3       foo(1000000000); // output: 1000000000
4       foo(1000000000 * 10); // output: 1410065408
5       foo((long)1000000000 * 10); // output: 10000000000
6       
7       long l = 1000000000 * 10;
8       foo(l); // output: 1410065408
9       //long m = 10000000000; // compile error
10  }

    static void foo(long l){
        System.out.println(l);
    }
}
```

Why line 4 output: 1410065408 instead of 10000000000?

Why line 9 is a compile error? can't the compiler create a `Long` as the expected type is a `Long`?

Answer (score 4):

By default, integer literals are `int`s -- which means they abide by int arithmetic, and they can't represent numbers larger than an `int` can hold. Note that in your line 4, the two ints are first multiplied (using int arithmetic) and only then is the result casted to a `long` -- but by then it's too late, and the overflow has already happened.

To put a `long` literal, just append `L` to it:

```
long m = 10000000000L;
```

(A lowercase 'l' would also compile, but that looks like a digit '1' so you should avoid it; use the capital 'L' so that it stands out).

Comment: Surprised that   (int *  int) doesn't get promoted to a long result when it will overflow an int.

Answer (score 0):

Literals default to int unless otherwise specified. Instead of casting with `(long)` you can add `L` to the end of your literal to note that it should be of type `long`, in the same way that `1.1` is a `double` and `1.1f` is a `float`.

```
foo(1000000000L * 10); // output: 10000000000
```

and

```
long m = 10000000000L;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you perform any operation in java, the compiler tries to make an implicit cast to the operands transforming both of them to the bigger datatype. (int / int = result is allways int).

Add an explicit cast to your literals (defaulted to `int`) as indicated in other answers:

```
long l = 1000000000L * 10;
```